# ros as root - common bug, when workspace is in /home/user/ros_workspace

Tags: ros, root, ros-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey guys,

I tried to run some ROS-Packages as root and got this:

> Warning: error while crawling
> /home/username:
> boost::filesystem::status: Permission
> denied: "/home/username/.gvfs"

According to some google research, this is a common bug - somehow .gvfs denies any access for anyone who is not the user.

My setup of shell&environment was absolutly fine, once I copied the workspace to another path(/home/ros_workspace) there was no problem :-)

This is no real question, but I thought it might be helpful to mention this problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/36282/ros-as-root---common-bug,-when-workspace-is-in-/home/user/ros_workspace/) by [Flowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/2441/flowers/) on ROS Answers with karma: 342 on 2012-06-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Asomerville](https://answers.ros.org/users/351/asomerville/) on 2012-06-12**:
Probably best to file a bug instead: http://www.ros.org/wiki/Tickets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why are you running ROS packages as root from the workspace of another user?
That is likely that actual problem.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2012-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Flowers](https://answers.ros.org/users/2441/flowers/) on 2012-06-12**:
Because I thought it would be useful in that situation ;-) and the system has one user(me) and root...usually root should have access to everything which it has not, so I reported this.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-06-12**:
Good to be aware of. The message is "don't run as root", and especially "don't build anything as root".